# Updating total from quantity and price in Meteor collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-collection-hooks

I have three fields `quantity`, `price`, and `total`.

I am only updating `quantity` and `price`, so `total` should be calculated automatically.

How can I make sure `total` is always updated correctly? I guess I should use a collection hook.

Comment: Is `total` just `quantity` * `price`, or is it based on something else in your collection? How are you doing the updates (allow/deny vs methods)?

Comment: I am updating quantity and price through an autoform with `type="update"`.

Comment: Simplest solution is not to store `total`.  Always calculate it when you need it.

Comment: Not storing it at all is great *unless* you have to search for it.

Comment: It won't be appropriate in all scenarios, but you can use the MongoDB aggregation framework to find a calculated value:  
Orders.aggregate(
    [ {$project: 
        {date: 1, 
         item: 1, 
         total: {$multiply: ["$price", "$quantity"]}
        }
      }, 
      {$match: {total: searchTerm}}
    ]
  );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using autoform and simple schema, just use an autovalue

```
'price': { type: Number },
'quantity': { type: Number },
'total': {
  type: Number,
  autoValue: function () {
    const price = this.field('price');
    const quantity = this.field('quantity');
    if (price.isSet && quantity.isSet) {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return quantity.value * price.value;
      } else {
        return { $set: quantity.value * price.value };
      }
    }
  }  
}
```